# How Do I Set A Style On A UserControl Dependency Property?

Tags: wpf, xaml, user-controls

I have created a UserControl with a dependency property named HighlightedBorderBrush.
I registered the dependency property as follows:

```
    public static readonly DependencyProperty HighlightedBorderBrushProperty =
    DependencyProperty.Register("Highlighted_BorderBrush", typeof(Brush),
                                typeof(MyUserControl),
                                new FrameworkPropertyMetadata(Brushes.Black));

    public Brush HighlightedBorderBrush
    {
        get { return (Brush)GetValue(HighlightedBorderBrushProperty); }
        set {SetValue(HighlightedBorderBrushProperty, value); }
    }
```

In the code where I use the UserControl I am able to set the HighlightedBorderBrush property directly in XAML as follows:

```
    <local:MyUserControl HighlightedBorderBrush="Red" />
```

This works fine.  However, when I attempt to use a style I get an error:  "Exception has been thrown by the target of an invocation."

Here is the code where I attempt to use a style:

```
    <!-- Define a style for the user control -->
    <Window.Resources>
        <Style x:Key="UserControlStyle" TargetType="{x:Type local:MyUserControl}">
            <Setter Property="HighlightedBorderBrush" Value="Red"/>
        </Style
    </Window.Resources>

    .
    .
    .

    <!-- Use a Style to set the HighlightedBorderBrush property -->
    <local:MyUserControl Style="{StaticResource UserControlStyle}" />
```

I'm guessing that I am missing something obvious but cannot figure it out.  Help!

Comment: Property name in DP registration should be `HighlightedBorderBrush` instead of `Highlighted_BorderBrush`. Is that typo?

Comment: Also post inner exception which gives more clear picture of an error.

Comment: Thank you, Rohit!  As I said, I was probably missing something obvious and I was!  It was indeed a typo in my code:  "Highlighted_BorderBrush" should have been "HighlightedBorderBrush" and when I corrected the typo my code worked fine.  Thank you again!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As mentioned property name is incorrect in DependencyProperty registration.

Property name in DP registration should be `HighlightedBorderBrush` instead of `Highlighted_BorderBrush`.

Comment: Your welcome Peter. Please accept it so that question can be closed.